# How to populate Mongoose DB field with a value from another schema

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have three schemas:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  username: String,
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

```
const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    requred: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
  isCompleted: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  collaborators: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      default: [],
    },
  ],
});
```

```
const collaboratorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  taskId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Task",
    required: true,
  },
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  // NOTE: Adding collaborator status
  invitationStatus: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["accepted", "rejected", "pending"],
    default: "pending",
    validate: {
      validator: function (v) {
        return ["accepted", "rejected", "pending"].includes(v);
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I'm trying to write an express js route to return all tasks for user, but populating the `collaborators` array of the `task` to include `invitationStatus` as referred from the `collaboratorSchema`.

I know this should be possible because the `collaboratorSchema` has `taskId`, `userId`, and `invitationStatus` in which two of those i can match from the `taskSchema` i.e `collaboratorSchema's taskId = taskSchema's _id` and `collaboratorSchema's userId = taskSchema's collaborator[index]._id`

here's what i have so far:

```
router.post("/", async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const userId = req.body.userId;

    if (ObjectId.isValid(userId)) {
      const tasks = await Task.find({ owner: req.body.userId })
        .populate("collaborators", "-password")
        .populate("owner", "-password")
        .exec();

      res.status(200).json(tasks);
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid User Id" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Error" });
  }
});
```

whose sample output would be something like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "6431bb0a668c75913ead3afb",
        "title": "Organize team meeting",
        "description": "Discuss project progress and upcoming deadlines",
        "isCompleted": true,
        "owner": {
            "_id": "63f7c47c595aab4eb0165135",
            "username": "sholmes",
            "name": "Sherlock Holmes",
            "email": "sholmes@gmail.com"
        },
        "collaborators": [
            {
                "_id": "63f844a3e4230b11711b97f4",
                "username": "jbourne",
                "name": "Jason Bourne",
                "email": "jbourne@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "_id": "63f7c47c595aab4eb0165135",
                "username": "sholmes",
                "name": "Sherlock Holmes",
                "email": "sholmes@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "6431bb0a668c75913ead3afc",
        "title": "Develop new feature",
        "description": "Create UI for new feature and integrate with backend",
        "isCompleted": true,
        "owner": {
            "_id": "63f7c47c595aab4eb0165135",
            "username": "sholmes",
            "name": "Sherlock Holmes",
            "email": "sholmes@gmail.com"
        },
        "collaborators": [
            {
                "_id": "63f7c47c595aab4eb0165136",
                "username": "jbond",
                "name": "James Bond",
                "email": "jbond@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "_id": "63f7c47c595aab4eb0165135",
                "username": "sholmes",
                "name": "Sherlock Holmes",
                "email": "sholmes@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "_id": "63f866d159b75af7fa28231d",
                "username": "jwick",
                "name": "John Wick",
                "email": "jwick@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "6431bb0a668c75913ead3afd",
        "title": "Complete marketing report",
        "description": "Analyze market trends and create report",
        "isCompleted": false,
        "owner": {
            "_id": "63f7c47c595aab4eb0165135",
            "username": "sholmes",
            "name": "Sherlock Holmes",
            "email": "sholmes@gmail.com"
        },
        "collaborators": [
            {
                "_id": "63f844a3e4230b11711b97f4",
                "username": "jbourne",
                "name": "Jason Bourne",
                "email": "jbourne@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "_id": "63f7c47c595aab4eb0165136",
                "username": "jbond",
                "name": "James Bond",
                "email": "jbond@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So, what i just need is the collaborators's array to also include `invitationStatus` field like this:

```
{
        "_id": "6431bb0a668c75913ead3afb",
        "title": "Organize team meeting",
        "description": "Discuss project progress and upcoming deadlines",
        "isCompleted": true,
        "owner": {
            "_id": "63f7c47c595aab4eb0165135",
            "username": "sholmes",
            "name": "Sherlock Holmes",
            "email": "sholmes@gmail.com"
        },
        "collaborators": [
            {
                "_id": "63f844a3e4230b11711b97f4",
                "username": "jbourne",
                "name": "Jason Bourne",
                "email": "jbourne@gmail.com",
>!                 "invitationStatus": "pending",  // <--  i need this

            },
            {
                "_id": "63f7c47c595aab4eb0165135",
                "username": "sholmes",
                "name": "Sherlock Holmes",
                "email": "sholmes@gmail.com",
                "invitationStatus": "accepted", // <--  i need this
            }
        ]
    }
```